# How to convert (convas chart) to either (Chart , or system.drawing.image , or stream , or []byte ) where I can use it in c# to generate pdf

Tags: javascript, c#, pdf, canvas, chart.js

[image: this is the page]

I have this chart which will print number of visitors per hours in specified year

and this is the function that will take out the data for specified year from database and I will keep them in hidden field X-axis & Y-axis in order to draw the bar chart with great resolution , and  user can interact with it

```
 public bool barchart(string val)
        {

            bool exists = false;


            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            //  string query = string.Format("select to_char(datetime_in,'HH24:MM') as hour,count(*)  from visits where   to_char(datetime_in,'YYYY')='" + val + "'  group by to_char(datetime_in,'HH24:MM') order by to_char(datetime_in,'HH24:MM')");
            string query = "";
            if (db.dbType == "mysql")
            {

                query = string.Format("Select DATE_FORMAT(datetime_in, '%H')  as hours,count(*) as visits from visits where DATE_FORMAT(datetime_in, '%Y') ='" + val + "'  group by DATE_FORMAT(datetime_in, '%H') order by DATE_FORMAT(datetime_in, '%H')");
                Debug.WriteLine(" Barchart query : " + query);
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query);
                String constr = mysqlConnectionString;
                MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt); con.Close();
            }
            else
            {

                query = string.Format("Select TO_CHAR(datetime_in,'HH24') as hour,count(*) from visits where to_char(datetime_in,'YYYY')='" + val + "'  group by TO_CHAR(datetime_in,'HH24') order by TO_CHAR(datetime_in,'HH24')");
                Debug.WriteLine(" Barchart query : " + query);
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(query);
                String constr = connectionString;
                OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(constr);
                con.Open();
                OracleDataAdapter sda = new OracleDataAdapter();
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                sda.Fill(dt); con.Close();
            }




            string yAxis = "";
            string xAxis = "";
            DataView vieww = new DataView(dt);
            foreach (DataRowView roww in vieww)
            {
                exists = true;

                xAxis += roww["hours"] + ",";
                yAxis += roww["visits"] + ",";


            }
            hdn_Yaxis.Value = yAxis;
            hdn_Xaxis.Value = xAxis;

            return exists;


        }
```

after I take x-axis and y-axis in hidden field I will draw them in page using Canvas element

```
     <canvas height='300' id='canvas_barchart' width='750'></canvas>
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_Yaxis" runat="server" />
     <asp:HiddenField ID="hdn_Xaxis" runat="server" />
```

and I will use this script to draw the bar chart with help of X-axis and Y-Axis hidden fields

```
     <script src="Chart_js/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
         <script src='js/Chart.min.js'></script>

<script language="javascript" >

    var Bar_yAxis = document.getElementById('<%=hdn_Yaxis.ClientID%>').value;
    var Bar_xAxis = document.getElementById('<%=hdn_Xaxis.ClientID%>').value;


    //alert("Y = " + yAxis + " X = " + xAxis);
    Bar_yAxis = Bar_yAxis.substring(0, Bar_yAxis.length - 1);
    Bar_xAxis = Bar_xAxis.substring(0, Bar_xAxis.length - 1);


    var Bar_arrayx = Bar_xAxis.split(',');



    var Bar_arrayY = Bar_yAxis.split(',').map(function (item) {
        return parseInt(item, 10);
    });


   var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_barchart");

 var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx,
{

    type : 'bar',

   data: {

labels: Bar_arrayx,
datasets: [
    {

        fill: true,
        fillColor: "rgba(255, 153, 29,.8)",
        lineTension: 0.1,
        backgroundColor: "rgba(255, 153, 29,.8)",

        borderColor: "rgba(255, 153, 29,1)",
        borderCapStyle: 'butt',
        borderDash: [],
        borderDashOffset: 0,
        borderJoinStyle: 'miter',


        pointBorderColor: "rgba(255, 153, 29,1)",
        pointBackgroundColor: "#fff",
        pointBorderWidth: 1,
        pointHoverRadius: 5,
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255, 153, 29,1)",
        pointHoverBorderColor: "rgba(255, 153, 29,1)",
        pointHoverBorderWidth: 2,
        pointRadius: 1,
        pointHitRadius: 10,


        data: Bar_arrayY,
        spanGaps: false,
    } 
]
} ,
options : 
{ 

        scales: {
                   yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                            }]
                },
        tooltips : {

            callbacks : { // HERE YOU CUSTOMIZE THE LABELS
               title : function() {
                    return null; //'eVMS';
                },
                beforeLabel : function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return null; //'Date' + ': ' + tooltipItem.xLabel;
                },
                label : function(tooltipItem, data) {
                    return   null;
                },
                   afterLabel : function(tooltipItem, data) {
                   if( parseInt(tooltipItem.yLabel) == 1) return tooltipItem.yLabel + " hours";
                   else return tooltipItem.yLabel + " hours";
                }

            }

   }
    }
});


</script>
```

now I have to print the chart into pdf using this function :

```
 using (MemoryStream stream1 = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph(new Chunk(new iTextSharp.text.pdf.draw.LineSeparator(0.0F, 100.0F, iTextSharp.text.Color.BLACK, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, 1)));
                pdfDoc.Add(p2);

                pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));
                pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));

                PieChart.SaveImage(stream1, ChartImageFormat.Png);
                iTextSharp.text.Image chartImage1 = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream1.GetBuffer());
                chartImage1.ScalePercent(75f); 
                chartImage1.SpacingBefore = 100f;

                chartImage1.SpacingAfter = 110f;
                pdfDoc.Add(chartImage1); pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));// pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n")); pdfDoc.Add(new Phrase("\n"));
                //byte[] bytes1 = stream.ToArray();

            }
```

now I have 3 options to pint the chart into pdf :

1) from front-end try to convert canvas element into C# Chart variable  and then  use SaveImage() to save the stream and then print it as pdf

2) from front-end try to convert canvas element into C# system.drawing.image and then use iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(system.drawing.image img) and I can print it in pdf

3) from front-end try to convert canvas element into stream or []byte and then use iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(stream.getbuffer()) and I can print it in pdf

I don't want to use the barchart itself like `barchart.saveimage()` because the resolution in not at all good , I prefer to draw it in canvas for high resolution

I don't want to print it directly from javascript because its only picture and we already built the whole report using iTextsharp in C#, and I don't want to write the report again , so  I want to print the chart image  only in some places and the rest of report is already built

I know that i can save it in my server then from the server I can print it but, this is not good way for my project because we have multiple users and the images will be conflicted

And if you have another ways please let me know

please help

Answer (score 0):

Once you have this:

```
var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_barchart");
```

...and you've then drawn your bar chart, you can do something like this:

```
var context = ctx.getContext('2d');
var pixels = context.getImageData(0, 0, ctx,width, ctx.height).data;
```

At that point you have an array of bytes representing your image. See https://www.w3schools.com/tags/canvas_getimagedata.asp to get an idea of how that byte array is structured.

Edit: This gives more detail on how the image data is structured: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData

Comment: its not working may be there is spelling mistake  , did you mean to get the byte of the image data but how you will pass them in c#

Comment: I can only help you as far as the JavaScript part -- I don't know much about C# or how you're passing data around. I was hoping that once you had the byte[] (and I hope that much of what I wrote works) you could take it from there.

Comment: if I take the byte of the image and set it in the code then the picture become black

Comment: Are you sure that you drew the image first before calling getImageData()?

Comment: yes once I reach  var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas_barchart") then all the bytes is configured , but the thing is that how to use this byte as source of Image Element  I want at least to use document.getElementById("myImage").src = bytes_of_the_Canvas_image   but also its not work :(

Comment: do you know how to pass variable content into image src